# in OkHTTP how do I set the keep-alive to false?

Tags: okhttp

The default behavior for OkHttpClient is to set keep-alive to true.
For our specific use case, I need to set this to false.

I am not finding any setting in the Java source to do this.

Has anyone run into this?

I am on OkHttpClient 3.8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2031

u can run demo code like

```
okHttpClient.setConnectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 0));
```

or add header like Connection: close.

The source code which give you a clue to this behavior is:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/480c20e46bb1745e280e42607bbcc73b2c953d97/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnectionPool.kt#L108

Comment: Use `Connection: close` as a header. You can do it in an interceptor if you want it everywhere.

Comment: Jason, I tried to set this header but it didn't work. This would have been a great option as I don't have to modify the connection pool.

Comment: I do have to admit, that this strategy of not reusing the connection has big performance degradation. Use it only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: add header like Connection: close. means ask the web-server to close the connection, but not disable the keepalive.